# How to differentiate cmd processes (batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a script that uses *tasklist|find "cmd"* to track if a batch file I specify is running. This works if only one batch file is running, however. If more than one batch file is running, my script tracks all batch scripts since all batch processes are named cmd.exe. **How can I track (using the above command) a specific batch file if the process names for all batch processes are the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `title` command and include some variable (like the time) in the title assigned. In that way, `tasklist /v` will have a different value for each `cmd` line.